# Need to resize features in XGBoost

Tags: model, train

I am scaling all the numeric features in my train data in values between 0 and 1 but is it truly necessary? Does the algorithm performance is improved doing so or it can deal with different ranges of numeric values?

Comment: Do you know how decision trees work?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I know the concept, and my guess is that it can split data in a independent way of scale, but I am finding a lot of codes normalizing data before apply decision trees algorithms.

Comment: You're right, a decision tree doesn't care about scale.  Possibly they were testing multiple methodologies, and some were sensitive to scale?

Comment: I found codes specifically for XGBoost package in R and Python doing it. So I was in doubt. But thank you, I think you answered it.

Comment: @MatthewDrury you should probably write up an actual answer based on your comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one is using XGBoost in the default mode (booster:gbtree) it shouldn't matter as the splits won't get affected by the scaling of feature columns. But if the booster model is gblinear, there is a possibility that the largely different variance of a particular feature column/attribute might screw up the small regression done at the nodes.

Comment: Fast learner! You might want to upvote my answer to your question similar to this one!

Comment: Thanks guys! I studied more about the method and understood how it works. Actually for the linear regression problem I was working I got a big improvement treating the skewness of the variables using Box-Cox and log transformations. Scale the values did not work.